# jQuery load pictures from xml

Tags: jquery, xml, image, flash, prettyphoto

Hi i wan't to load pictures from xml and thel load it via prettyphoto here is my xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<images>

<image source="Zdjecia/Galeria/Kategoria1/Miniaturki/image1.jpg"                

lightbox="Zdjecia/Galeria/Kategoria1/Duze/image1.jpg"/>


<image source="Zdjecia/Galeria/Kategoria1/Miniaturki/image2.jpg"                

lightbox="Zdjecia/Galeria/Kategoria1/Duze/image2.jpg"/>

    <image source="Zdjecia/Galeria/Kategoria1/Miniaturki/image3.jpg"        

lightbox="Zdjecia/Galeria/Kategoria1/Duze/image3.jpg"/>

    <image source="Zdjecia/Galeria/Kategoria1/Miniaturki/image4.jpg"        

lightbox="Zdjecia/Galeria/Kategoria1/Duze/image4.jpg"/>

    <image source="Zdjecia/Galeria/Kategoria1/Miniaturki/image5.jpg"        

lightbox="Zdjecia/Galeria/Kategoria1/Duze/image5.jpg"/>

    <image source="Zdjecia/Galeria/Kategoria1/Miniaturki/image6.jpg"        

lightbox="Zdjecia/Galeria/Kategoria1/Duze/image6.jpg"/>

    <image source="Zdjecia/Galeria/Kategoria1/Miniaturki/image7.jpg"        

lightbox="Zdjecia/Galeria/Kategoria1/Duze/image7.jpg"/>

    <image source="Zdjecia/Galeria/Kategoria1/Miniaturki/image8.jpg"        

lightbox="Zdjecia/Galeria/Kategoria1/Duze/image8.jpg"/>

    <image source="Zdjecia/Galeria/Kategoria1/Miniaturki/image9.jpg"        

lightbox="Zdjecia/Galeria/Kategoria1/Duze/image9.jpg"/>

    <image source="Zdjecia/Galeria/Kategoria1/Miniaturki/image10.jpg"       

lightbox="Zdjecia/Galeria/Kategoria1/Duze/image10.jpg"/>
</images>
```

Here is my js function :

```
jQuery(window).ready(function($) {
        $.get("XML/Kategoria1.xml",{},function(xml){
            $('image',xml).each(function(i) {
                lightbox = $(this).find("lightbox").text();
            });
        });



        $.fn.prettyPhoto();
        });


        function openLightbox(path) {

            $.prettyPhoto.open(lightbox);

            }
```

First image that i want to open is "path" it is sending from flash and next images i want to load from xml called "lightbox" but this script won't work anyone can tell my why or explain me how to do it?? Please for help.

---

This is my html file :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="pl" xml:lang="pl">
    <head>
        <title>portfolio</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />



<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/prettyPhoto.css" media="all"/>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.prettyPhoto.js"></script>  
     <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/swfobject.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/swffit.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            swfobject.embedSWF("portfolio.swf", "my_flash", "980", "640", "9.0.0", "", false, {wmode:'transparent'});
            swffit.fit("my_flash"); 

$(document).ready(function($) {
    $.get("xml/kategoria1.xml",{},function(xml){
    $('image',xml).each(function(i) {
        lightbox = $(this).find("lightbox").text();
        openLightbox(lightbox);
    });
});

function openLightbox(path) {
    $.prettyPhoto.open(path);
}
        </script>







        <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        html, body { height:100%; background-color: #000000;}
        body { margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden; }
        #flashContent { width:100%; height:100%; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="my_flash">
            <object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" width="100%" height="100%" id="portfolio" align="middle">
                <param name="movie" value="portfolio.swf" />
                <param name="quality" value="best" />
                <param name="bgcolor" value="#000000" />
                <param name="play" value="true" />
                <param name="loop" value="true" />
                <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
                <param name="scale" value="showall" />
                <param name="menu" value="true" />
                <param name="devicefont" value="false" />
                <param name="salign" value="lt" />
                <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
                <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
                <!--[if !IE]>-->
                <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="portfolio.swf" width="100%" height="100%">
                    <param name="movie" value="portfolio.swf" />
                    <param name="quality" value="best" />
                    <param name="bgcolor" value="#000000" />
                    <param name="play" value="true" />
                    <param name="loop" value="true" />
                    <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
                    <param name="scale" value="showall" />
                    <param name="menu" value="true" />
                    <param name="devicefont" value="false" />
                    <param name="salign" value="lt" />
                    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
                    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
                <!--<![endif]-->
                    <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflash">
                        <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Pobierz odtwarzacz Adobe Flash Player" />
                    </a>
                <!--[if !IE]>-->
                </object>
                <!--<![endif]-->
            </object>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

I try to do something and this script load from xml a single image, any ideas how to load all "lightbox" images from xml  ??

```
jQuery(window).ready(function($) {
    $.fn.prettyPhoto();
    $.get("xml/kategoria1.xml",{},function(xml){
    $('image',xml).each(function(i) {
        lightbox = $(this).find("lightbox").text();
      openLightbox(lightbox)
    });
});
});

function openLightbox(path) {
    $.prettyPhoto.open(path);
```

Answer (score 0):

Swap the above code with this...

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
    $.get("XML/Kategoria1.xml",{},function(xml){
    $('image',xml).each(function(i) {
        lightbox = $(this).find("lightbox").text();
        openLightbox(lightbox);
    });
});

function openLightbox(path) {
    $.prettyPhoto.open(path);
}
```

Comment: When i'm change to this code the internet browser starts using 100% of procesor and stop working :(

Comment: I don't know prettyPhoto and without the rest of your code it's impossible to know why.  Can you give a URL?

Comment: i can send u to mail if u want because at this moment i don't have acces to server.

Comment: i have only two functions in html file rest is in flash i called function from flash via externalinterfaceCall and this is the function openLightbox and all i want to do is open path sended from flash it is lightbox in xml file and then load rest lightbox images from xml file because normal it opens only a single image in prettyphoto without previous and next buttons.

and the question is how to load the rest of images from xml

Comment: Or maybe you know how to do it with another lightbox i don't care i wan't just open big image in lightbox with buttons previous and next

Comment: Surely you don't want to open a lightbox for every image in the xml file?

Comment: I have an as3 xml grid gallery. When I click on the thumbnail i want to open a big image in prettyphoto or another lightbox. But from flash i can send a single image and i know how to do it, but i want to open image that i clicked + rest of images. Just clicked image and then all of the images after click button prev or next in lightbox